# Center an image inserted with after: pseudo-element; can't use spans

Tags: css, centering, pseudo-element

I'm pulling in a tumblr feed using tumblr's code, and using after: to add an image as a separator between posts.  I'd like to center the image, but haven't had luck doing so.  Since tumblr's generating the content, not me, I don't think I can use span tags, which seems to be the usual answer.  Any other ideas?

Page showing feed in use: [lumn.net/index.shtml](http://www.lumn.net/index.shtml)

CSS:

```
.tumblr_post:after {
    content: url(../img/flower.png);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 42px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please reproduce on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, where we can see, and edit, the code in action.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
.tumblr_post:after {
    content: url("../img/flower.png");
    display: block;
    margin: 42px auto 24px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

While the answer from Zoltan Toth works, it's got a bunch of code that does nothing for the desired effect. This should do the trick and with less code.

```
.tumblr_post:after {
    content: url("../img/flower.png");
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working solution on all screens :

```
.produit-col .img-produit::after{
    content: '';
    background: url("../img/icone.png") center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
```